# How to access an array within a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm working on my to do list app. Most of it works fine, but I still get this issue 
(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined). For some reason I cannot understand yet, I cannot pass the array `toDoList` to the `searchList` function in order to filter the relevant elements for my dynamic search feature. Would anybody be willing to help?

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
let toDoList = [];
const input = document.querySelector(".add");
const search = document.querySelector(".search");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const removeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("remove");
const span = document.querySelector("h1 span");
const key = 0

const addItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  ul.innerHTML = ""
  toDoList.push(input.value)
  toDoList.forEach((toDoElement, key) => {
    const task = document.createElement("li")
    task.dataset.key = key;
    key++
    task.className = "task";
    task.textContent = toDoElement
    task.innerHTML += ` <button>usuń</button>`
    ul.appendChild(task);
    span.textContent = toDoList.length;
    task.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", removeItem)
  })

}

const searchList = (e, toDoList) => {
  ul.innerHTML = ""
  if (search.value === "") {
    toDoList.forEach((toDoElement, key) => {
      const task = document.createElement("li")
      task.dataset.key = key;
      key++
      task.className = "task";
      task.textContent = toDoElement
      task.innerHTML += ` <button>usuń</button>`
      ul.appendChild(task);
      span.textContent = toDoList.length;
      task.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", removeItem)
    })
  } else {
    const searchText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    console.log(searchText);
    console.log(toDoList);
    let result = toDoList.filter(li => li.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(searchText))
    console.log(result)
  }
}

const removeItem = (e) => {
  e.target.parentNode.remove();
  const index = e.target.parentNode.dataset.key;
  toDoList.splice(index, 1)
  span.textContent = toDoList.length;
}


button.addEventListener("click", addItem);
search.addEventListener("input", searchList)
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="add">
  <button>Dodaj zadanie</button>
</form>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="search">
</form>
<h1>Liczba zadań: <span></span></h1>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stored `toDoList` globally, so defining a function variable named `toDoList` overwrote it in that scope with whatever was passed in (which was nothing, so it was `undefined`). As others said, just removing the parameter from `searchList` was sufficient.

I tried to tidy the code up as well so it is more readable, and I added missing semicolons. They are not optional! ;-)

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const input = document.querySelector(".add");
const search = document.querySelector(".search");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const removeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("remove");
const span = document.querySelector("h1 span");

var toDoList = [];
const key = 0;

const addItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  ul.innerHTML = "";
  toDoList.push(input.value);
  toDoList.forEach((toDoElement, key) => {
    const task = document.createElement("li");
    task.dataset.key = key++;
    task.className = "task";
    task.innerHTML = toDoElement + "<button>Remove</button>";
    task.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", removeItem);

    ul.appendChild(task);
    span.textContent = toDoList.length;
  });
}

const removeItem = (e) => {
  e.target.parentNode.remove();
  const index = e.target.parentNode.dataset.key;
  toDoList.splice(index, 1);
  span.textContent = toDoList.length;
}

const searchList = (e) => {
  ul.innerHTML = "";
  if (!search.value)
    toDoList.forEach((toDoElement, key) => {
      const task = document.createElement("li");
      task.dataset.key = key++;
      task.className = "task";
      task.innerHTML = toDoElement + "<button>Remove</button>";
      task.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", removeItem);

      ul.appendChild(task);
      span.innerHTML = toDoList.length;
    });

  else {
    const searchText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let result = toDoList.filter(
      li => li.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
    );

    console.clear();
    console.log("Search:", searchText);
    console.log("ToDoList:", toDoList);
    console.log("Results:", result);
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addItem);
search.addEventListener("input", searchList);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>toDoList</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="add">
    <button>Add task</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <form>
    <label for="search_input">Search</label><br>
    <input id="search_input" type="text" class="search">
  </form>
  <h1>Num tasks: <span>0</span></h1>
  <ul></ul>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback and fixing the code! So you mean that because I passed toDoList array along with e, I actually overwrote the original toDoList array in the global scope?

Comment: Right, so run that function in your brain. If we initialize it with no variables, `searchList() { ... }`, and reference `toDoList` in that function, it will be referencing the global variable `toDoList`, which is where we're managing our data. BUT, if you define it as `searchList(var1, toDoList) { ... }`, and you reference `toDoList`, that function is looking at its local variable, which isn't what we want.

Comment: To take it a step further, you actually *could* make that function work even when defining a local variable with the same name - a global variable `myGlobalVariable` is actually, behind the scenes, `window.myGlobalVariable`, and you can reference it that way if you need to. I'm not trying to bog you down in the details here as much as give you a better picture of variable scoping, and why your call to `toDoList` returned `undefined`.

Comment: Copy that! What I did not understand was the whole "passing idea". I just thought that it makes the variable more accessible in the function (but it's still the same variable declared in the global scope). Now it makes sense, thanks for helping me avoiding potential mistakes in the future.

Comment: No worries, and my grandpa comment about semicolons is only because they're how Javascript knows a statement has ended - we can suck out every newline and indentation in JS code and it should compile (`alert(1);alert(2);alert(3);`), but that only works if semicolons tell it where to stop reading a statement! The parser does a good job of guessing, but you'll save yourself a situation where you can't get past a horrible bug only to find out it was because of missing punctuation (super awful).

Comment: I totally get it. Time to revise where to put semicolons, then!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `toDoList` from argument in `searchList const searchList = (e, toDoList) => {` and remove `textContent` from `li.textContent.toLowerCase()`

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
let toDoList = [];
const input = document.querySelector(".add");
const search = document.querySelector(".search");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const removeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("remove");
const span = document.querySelector("h1 span");
const key = 0

const addItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  ul.innerHTML = ""
  toDoList.push(input.value)
  toDoList.forEach((toDoElement, key) => {
    const task = document.createElement("li")
    task.dataset.key = key;
    key++
    task.className = "task";
    task.textContent = toDoElement
    task.innerHTML += ` <button>usuń</button>`
    ul.appendChild(task);
    span.textContent = toDoList.length;
    task.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", removeItem)
  })

}

const searchList = (e) => {
  ul.innerHTML = ""
  if (search.value === "") {
    toDoList.forEach((toDoElement, key) => {
      const task = document.createElement("li")
      task.dataset.key = key;
      key++
      task.className = "task";
      task.textContent = toDoElement
      task.innerHTML += ` <button>usuń</button>`
      ul.appendChild(task);
      span.textContent = toDoList.length;
      task.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", removeItem)
    })
  } else {
    const searchText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    console.log(searchText);
    console.log(toDoList);
    let result = toDoList.filter(li =>li.toLowerCase().includes(searchText));
    console.log(result)
  }
}

const removeItem = (e) => {
  e.target.parentNode.remove();
  const index = e.target.parentNode.dataset.key;
  toDoList.splice(index, 1)
  span.textContent = toDoList.length;
}


button.addEventListener("click", addItem);
search.addEventListener("input", searchList)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>toDoList</title>

</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="add">
    <button>Dodaj zadanie</button>
  </form>
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="search">
  </form>
  <h1>Liczba zadań: <span></span></h1>
  <ul></ul>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! So the error was caused by passing the toDoList array? Should TextContent  also  be deleted because it also caused the error?

Comment: @Jeknar, yes, you can directly access the textContent, you don't have to use it, if you see the structure of your toDoList while filtering

Answer (score 1):

Remove `toDoList` from function arguments here

---

const searchList = (e, <s>toDoList</s>) >>>>   const searchList = (e) =>
  ...

---

that will rise another exception when you are trying to filter `li`s based on search string which is not in scope of this question answer;